# How to compile manifest file with MC.exe?

Tags: c#, winapi, event-log

I want to use Windows Event Log in my c# application, so I'm trying to create an Event Provider. I already wrote the xml manifest file, but I've no ideia of how to compile it to generate resource definition file and a C# code file. I know that I have to use the MessageCompiler(MC.exe) and I already have the Windows SDK installed. Can someone give me instructions on how to proceed?

Comment: You can find examples with a websearch

Comment: Could you point me to one example? I want to know specifically how to use MC.exe, and I couldn't find anything about it.

Comment: I would do that with a web search.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the msdn link for the [mc.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa385638%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
I did a search and found this [document](http://download.microsoft.com/download/7/E/7/7E7662CF-CBEA-470B-A97E-CE7CE0D98DC2/eventing-guide.docx) explaining the use of mc.exe for event logging.
Hope that helps.

Answer (score 4):

(Hello from February 2021!)

- Microsoft recently changed how `mc.exe` works.
- Additionally, the `ecmangen.exe` ("Manifest Generator") GUI program that's documented in the "Programmers Guide to Eventing" *.docx file (dated 17th December 2010) [is no-longer included in the Windows 10 SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58635377/creating-windows-10-custom-logs-without-ecmangen-exe) **without a replacement**.

  - Microsoft's official recommendation is to download the last version of the Windows 10 SDK which included `ecmangen.exe`... annoyingly MSFT's reply doesn't specify *exactly which* SDK should be used, referring to it only by the (horribly ambiguous) name "Windows 10 Creators Edition".

    - (It annoys me no-end that they called this "Creators Edition" because it sounds like a separate SKU like Home Edition and Professional Edition)
    - Turns out they're referring to **Windows 10 SDK 10.0.15063.468** which you can download from [the SDK archive page](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/sdk-archive/).
    - It is not included in the Windows 10 SDK for the "Fall Creators Update" (which is version **10.0.16299.91**)
- The minimal install options to get `ecmangen.exe` is "Windows SDK for Desktop C++ x86 Apps" and "Windows SDK for Desktop C++ amd64 Apps" (you should install both).
- After you've installed the Windows 10 SDK version 10.0.15063.468, you'll find `ecmangen.exe` at:

  - `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\10.0.15063.0\x86\ecmangen.exe"`
  - `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\10.0.15063.0\x64\ecmangen.exe"`

    - (*yes*, the x64 binary is located under the x86 Program Files directory; *yes*, that's weird).

---

Now, [The documentation in the .NET example of using custom messages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.eventsourcecreationdata.messageresourcefile?view=netframework-4.8) says to run the command `mc -s EventLogMsgs.mc` to build the messages, however this is incorrect.

Instead, do this:

1. Ensure your manifest file from `ecmangen.exe` is valid (let's assume it's called "manifest.man").
2. Open a Visual Studio Developer Command Line prompt window

   - Ever since Windows 7.1 SDK, the SDK no-longer includes its Command Prompt shortcut in the start menu, so do this instead, so temporarily add it to your `PATH`, like so:

     1. Copy `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\10.0.15063.0\x64"` to the clipboard (including the double-quotes) - or whatever your actual install-path is.
     2. Open `cmd.exe` (or PowerShell first, then run `cmd`)
     3. Type this WITHOUT pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>: `SET PATH=%PATH%;`
     4. Paste the path from Step 1 (typically this is just a right-click, or the <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Insert</kbd> keystroke).

        - So you have `SET PATH=%PATH%;"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\10.0.15063.0\x64"`
     5. And then press <kbd>Enter</kbd>
     6. `cd %HOMEPATH%`
     7. `mc.exe -?` should now work.
3. In the same developer command-prompt as Step 2, `cd` to the directory containing your `manifest.man` and `messages.mc` files.
4. And then run `mc.exe messages.mc` and it should *just work*

   - You should now see `manifest.h` and `manifest.rc` (and some `.bin` and `TEMP.bin` files too...) output into the same directory.