# Creating Windows 10 Custom Logs without ecmangen.exe?

Tags: winapi, dll, windows-10, event-log

I'm trying to forward events in Windows 10, I found a great [github repo](https://github.com/palantir/windows-event-forwarding) that seems to have all the subscription XML stuff in it that I need, but when I go to install the channels (read, logs) so that the subscriptions receive everything, it doesn't work because the custom channels aren't there...the [github repo](https://github.com/palantir/windows-event-forwarding) contains a dll that supposively contains the custom channels and a manifest file (.man) you can use to create it yourself (seems to have alot of XML in it).

I didn't really trust a `.dll` I download from a github repo in my environment, so I decided that  since they tell you how to build the `.dll`.  The github repo references a [technet blog post](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/russellt/2016/05/18/creating-custom-windows-event-forwarding-logs/), that tells you how to build the `.dll`, but it's a bit dated being from 2016 and all.

I installed the Windows 10 SDK to try this out, but it doesn't include the file they told me to run to build the `.dll` from the manifest, mainly `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\bin\x64\ecmangen.exe`

I read in an [unresolved unanswered post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53028775/cannot-locate-ecmangen) that the executable was removed in from the Windows 10 SDK starting with version 10.0.16299.15, and that the op decided to just use an older version.

Was this tool replaced with something else?  I don't really want to use a DLL I found in a github repo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **ecmangen.exe** removal from the SDK: Ecmangen.exe will no longer ship
>   with the Windows SDK. Developers who rely on ecmangen for event
>   manifest creation are advised to install the **Windows Creators Edition**
>   of the SDK to obtain the file. Developers may also use **notepad or
>   other XML editor** of choice for manifest creation. A schema file is
>   available on MSDN to aid in manifest creation, for tools that support
>   it.

Refer to "[Windows 10 SDK Preview Build 16267 and Mobile Emulator Build 15240 Released](https://blogs.windows.com/windowsdeveloper/2017/08/22/windows-10-sdk-preview-build-16267-mobile-emulator-build-15240-released/)".

Refer to here for [Windows Creators Edition of the SDK](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/sdk-archive).

You can find **ecmangen.exe** at the following path:

[image]

Comment: So are you saying I need to download and install 16267 and look for `ecmangen.exe` there after I install it?

Comment: When I google `Windows 10 SDK Creators Edition` I end up back on this page: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/windows-10-sdk which I believe is the one I already downloaded and the `ecmangen.exe` file isn't there...what do I do?

Comment: Found the correct version here: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/sdk-archive

Comment: @leeand00 Glad to hear you got it.